# How can i detect when program are closed?

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes, kernel32

I am open application via kernel32.CreateProcessW. After this i get PID and Handle of application. Now, I want to detect when application are closed.

I am using WaitForSingleObject. But it is return only 0.

```
from ctypes import *
from defines import *
from datetime import *
import time

kernel32     = windll.kernel32

class test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.hProcess   = None


    def load(self):
        creation_flags      = CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
        startupinfo         = STARTUPINFO()
        process_information = PROCESS_INFORMATION()

        startupinfo.cb      = sizeof(startupinfo)

        if kernel32.CreateProcessW('C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe',
                                    None,
                                    None,
                                    None,
                                    None,
                                    creation_flags,
                                    None,
                                    None,
                                    byref(startupinfo),
                                    byref(process_information)):
            self.hProcess = process_information.hProcess
            print('CALC PID: {0}, Handle: {1}'.format(process_information.dwProcessId, process_information.hProcess))
        else:
            print('Error while opening process')

    def waitfor(self):
        print(kernel32.WaitForSingleObject(self.hProcess, 0xFFFFFFFF))

s = test()

s.load()
s.waitfor()
```

Comment: Show code.  See [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: I suspect the application you are running may be a stub.  Try `notepad.exe` which is a native windows application.  `calc.exe` on Windows 10, for example, is a native app that redirects to a Windows store app and exits immediately.

Comment: I want to detect when application closed

Answer (score 1):

Returning 0 is the value of `WAIT_OBJECT_0`, meaning the `hProcess` handle has signaled process exit.

As my comment stated, On Windows 10 `calc.exe` is a stub program.  It runs a *different* process (a Windows store app) and **immediately exits**.  So you *are* detecting **that** program (calc.exe) closed.  Change the code to use `notepad.exe` (a native windows app) which doesn't go on to launch a different app, and your script will wait until you close notepad.

Comment: Results are the same. I think i have to use Job Object.

Comment: I use job object and result is positive. How can i handle   apps like calc.exe? Job not work with this apps